# Devise/OmniAuth - LinkedIn: Email is blank in callback

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm using Devise 2.1.2 with multiple OmniAuth providers. My devise.rb file contains this line:

```
config.omniauth :linkedin, API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, :scope => 'r_emailaddress', :fields => ["email-address"]
```

It is currently stripped down to just email-address since that is the only thing acting strange. Taking a look inside `request.env['omniauth.auth'].info`, the `email` key is blank.

How come? I don't want to bypass validation, I wan't to use the email address from the users LinkedIn account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the thread link in Remus Rusanu's answer, I noticed [this post](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/17231#comment-17231) by a LinkedIn employee:

> Hey guys, we're working on a migration plan for existing applications. The new member permissions only apply to newly registered applications.
>
> Thanks!
>   Kamyar

Due to no patience, creating a new LinkedIn application allowed me to retrieve the user email address. How nice that they finally changed their mind about this.

Comment: hah, so now I need to update my code and make sure it works with them... last time I checked I did not want to use them exactly because of this. Technology at the speed of Intertubez...

Comment: @RemusRusanu Yup, not providing an email is kind of a deal breaker. I'm surprised that the thread is more than a year old, and that they just recently added it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that LinkedIn as a matter of policy [does not share the email over oauth](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3265), I'm not at all surprised.

Comment: +1 for the link, but the problem was solvable. Check out the [(currently) last comment](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/17231#comment-17231)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu LinkedIn just changed their policy: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog